# responsed data not displayed

Tags: java, android, json

After Login, I get back a JSON response from the server with the real name of the user. But it won't be displayed in TextView txtName. What is wrong with the code?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Button btnNeu;
    private Button btnAlle;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnNeu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.neu);
        btnAlle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alle);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        ...

    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**SQLiteHandler.java:**

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }

}
```

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Bitte Benutzername und Passwort eintragen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Login ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                        hideDialog();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                            // Check for error node in json
                            if (!error) {
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Create login session
                                session.setLogin(true);

                                // Launch main activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                        MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // Error in login. Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you connect to that "server"?

Comment: i connect to the server via another activity called LoginActivity. do you need that code too?

Comment: is it debugged and correclty leaves the data inside those tables and such?? really working?? did u open the database and assured the info is inserted? no errors in console, etc?

Comment: yes i get the data back from the server:
D/RegisterActivity(27015): Login Response: {"tag":"login","error":false,"uid":"55dcaa9f74baa3.71054226","user":{"name":"Martin","email":"***@***","created_at":"2015-08-25 19:49:19","updated_at":null}}
D/SessionManager(27015): User login session modified!

Comment: you then call `addUser`, allegedly with correct values and with no errors afterwards...

Comment: the only error in the log is: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
but i don't know what this is as i'm very new to programming android

Comment: no way of supposing/guessing/making up your error

Comment: I still *belive* you´re not writting the data in db or it does not get there before `if (cursor.getCount())` is executed

Comment: there `long id = ` is it zero? could you run a sql just after and get the row by `_id`? do all parameters have value, maybe you´re inserting ""?

Comment: I´m sure there´s code (code of yours) to get from that json to the db, or isn´t?

Comment: and I´m getting to the point of guessing you´re inserting nulls or "" to the session table. Could you, please, post that code??

Comment: in mainactivity i get the data from the database via hashmap as i know! i copied this code from a tutorial

Comment: pls post the call to `addUser` and how you get the data from json

Comment: i edited my question and added loginactivity.java

Comment: so... you **neeeeever** insert... see?. You need to get the "user.name" and "user.email" and call `addUser`. Up there in the `onResponse`. After checking for errors, before the new intent is raised

Comment: but when and where and how? i hope you don't get freaky because of me but i'm bad in programming :D

Comment: inside the `(!error)` if block. Call to `SQLiteHandler.addUser` with the values you can get from the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the code i have forgotten to insert in LoginActivity.java:
Now it is working

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Bitte Benutzername und Passwort eintragen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Login ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                        hideDialog();

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                            // Check for error node in json
                            if (!error) {
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Create login session
                                session.setLogin(true);

                                String uid = jObj.getString("uid");
                                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                                String name = user.getString("name");
                                String email = user.getString("email");
                                String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                                // Inserting row in users table
                                db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                                // Launch main activity
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                        MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // Error in login. Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        hideDialog();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: killing you with suffering could be a nice adventure :P... Let´s vote you up to see if you get to be a good SO user

Comment: i have to thank you really much! thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you for helping me! you are a great guy! :)